# In the Porter Stemming algorithm, what is the purpose of including an identity rule such as SS -> SS?

Tags: algorithm, information-retrieval, stemming

What is the point of the [Porter Stemmer algorithm](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/porter/stemmer.html) having a rule the converts `SS` to `SS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the rule `SS->SS` was not in the algorithm. Then words like `caress` would not be recognized at all and it would seem that algorithm can't do anything to reduce it to a stem. However, with the rule `SS->SS` the stemmer says: "I recognize the word `caress` and I reduce it to `caress`. I'm done". The alternative would be: "I can't do anything". Of course it  is fictitious work but what matters since is that it increases the precision of the stemmer. You can see that when the testing of the algorithm is being done. If this rule was not in the stemmer the results would have been different (worse). Look at the word list `[ridiculousness, caress]`

`Case 1.` Rule `SS->SS` in the algorithm.

Stemming:

```
caress (Step 1a)-> caress OK
ridiculousness (Step 2)-> ridiculous (step 4) -> ridicul OK
Success rate: 100%
```

`Case 2.` Rule `SS->SS` not in the algorithm.

Stemming:

```
caress -> fail OK
ridiculousness (Step 2)-> ridiculous (step 4) -> ridicul OK
Success rate: 50%
```

From practical point of view this rule doesn't matter. It's just a formalism.

Comment: Are you saying that the algorithm would not proceed to the next steps without this "operation"?

Comment: @Certainly not! Look at the word `ridiculousness`. Assume `SS->SS` was not in the algorithm. The word would be processed no early than `Step 2`.But  for some words ending with `SS`, like `caress`, the algorithm outputs `fail` - he could not find a rule. This would ultimately decrease the success rate.

Comment: So it's the equivalent of `SS -> do nothing but note that it was detected` ?

Comment: @Imray that's right! You should note that these kind of things are just formalisms. In the end, it doesn't matter. But the thing is if you have `SS->SS` more profit for  you since  your algorithm would deal with more cases.

Comment: @sve As far as I understand - what you wrote is not completely true; In step 1a there's the rule `S -> `, so the word `caress` (assuming there's no identity rule) would end up as `care` (which is still wrong, but the algorithm does not fail).

Comment: if it just increases success rate then what stops us from adding more identity rules to match as many words as possible?